# get total of a dynamically loaded table's column

Tags: html, jquery, json, ajax, dom

I am loading a table with the following jquery

```
function get_sales(customer_id,from_date,to_date){
         $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'ajax/sale_pl.php',
            data:{customer_id:customer_id,from_date:from_date,to_date:to_date},            
            dataType:"json",            
            success: function(response){ //console.log(response);                
                for(i=0; i<response.length; i++)
                {
                    $('#tdata').append('<tr>'+
                    '<td><a href="view_invoice.php?id='+response[i].invoice_id+'">'+response[i].invoice_id+'</a></td>'+
                    '<td>'+response[i].order_date+'</td>'+
                    '<td><h6 class="mb-1">'+response[i].product_name+'</h6></td>'+
                    '<td><h6 class="text-muted">'+response[i].product_code+'</h6></td>'+
                    '<td>'+response[i].sold_qty+'</td>'+
                    '<td>'+response[i].buy_price+'</td>'+
                     '<td>'+response[i].sell_price+'</td>'+                    
                    '<td>'+response[i].discount+'</td>'+                    
                    '<td>'+response[i].cost_price+'</td>'+
                    '<td>'+response[i].sold_price+'</td>'+
                    '<td class="profits">'+response[i].profit+'</td>'
                         + '</tr>'
                        );
                }                        
            }
        });
     }
```

here is my html code for the table

```
 <table class="table table-hover">
     <thead>
       <tr>
           <th>Invoice id</th>
           <th>Invoice Date</th>
           <th>Product Name</th>
           <th>Product Code</th>
           <th>Sale Qty</th>
           <th>Buy Price</th>
           <th>Sale Price</th>
           <th>Discount</th>
           <th>Cost Price</th>
           <th>Sold Price</th>
           <th>Profit</th>
          </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody id="tdata">                                     
        </tbody>
       <tfoot>
          <tr>
             <th colspan='10'>Total Profit</th>
              <th id="total_profit">0</th>
           </tr>
         </tfoot>
        </table>
```

what i am trying is to get the total of the profit column. I have tried the following one

```
function calcSub(){
    var totalProfit= 0;
    $(".profits").each(function(){
        totalPrice += parseInt($(this).val());
        $("#total_profit").html(totalPrice);
    });
};
```

but this is not working.

Please suggest me the solution. I am new to jQuery. Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: `var totalProfit= 0` need to be `var totalPrice= 0` ?

Comment: Also. How are you calling this function `calcSub()`  ?  Are you calling it after the `ajax` is completed or before ?

Comment: @AlwaysHelping if I call it after the ajax success, it returns nothing. but if I call it with separate button click after the page is loaded once, then it returns the result.

Comment: @BanglaTiger Ahh i see / know what the issue is. Are you calling the ajax from your own server or its like an API external server or something ?

Comment: I am working on localhost and data also being fetched from same @AlwaysHelping

Comment: @BanglaTiger are you calling `get_sales()` ? on page load ?

Comment: @AlwaysHelping yes.

Comment: @BanglaTiger See my answer now. Use that ajax code and function. All should be fine - let me know.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222232/discussion-between-always-helping-and-bangla-tiger).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [.text()](https://api.jquery.com/text/) not `.val()`. `.val()` is used when you are getting an `input` value. But in your case its simply getting the `.text()` of your `td` items.

**Edit:** Since the `two` (`get_sales` and `calcSub()`) functions are running simultaneously you need to use `async` function on and wait for the `await` for ajax to be completed on `success` before proceeding to `calcSub()` for your calculations

Add this code your file:

```
//get sales
async function get_sales(customer_id, from_date, to_date) {
  //Await for this to finish and then call total profit
  await $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'color.json',
    data: {
      customer_id: customer_id,
      from_date: from_date,
      to_date: to_date
    },
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response) { //console.log(response);                
        for (i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
          $('#tdata').append('<tr>' +
            '<td><a href="view_invoice.php?id=' + response[i].invoice_id + '">' + response[i].invoice_id + '</a></td>' +
            '<td>' + response[i].order_date + '</td>' +
            '<td><h6 class="mb-1">' + response[i].product_name + '</h6></td>' +
            '<td><h6 class="text-muted">' + response[i].product_code + '</h6></td>' +
            '<td>' + response[i].sold_qty + '</td>' +
            '<td>' + response[i].buy_price + '</td>' +
            '<td>' + response[i].sell_price + '</td>' +
            '<td>' + response[i].discount + '</td>' +
            '<td>' + response[i].cost_price + '</td>' +
            '<td>' + response[i].sold_price + '</td>' +
            '<td class="profits">' + response[i].profit + '</td>' +
            '</tr>'
          );
        }
    }
  });
  
  //call calculate total
  calcSub()
}

get_sales();

function calcSub() {
  var totalProfit = 0;
  $(".profits").each(function() {
    totalProfit += parseInt($(this).text());
    $("#total_profit").html(totalProfit);
  });
};
```

**Complete Working Demo as per the question**

```js
var response = [{
  "invoice_id": "Always Helping",
  "order_date": "03-02-2002",
  "product_name": "Always B +",
  "product_code": "foo@google.com.au",

  "sold_qty": "2",
  "buy_price": "2",
  "sell_price": "2",
  "discount": "2",
  "cost_price": "2",
  "sold_price": "2",
  "profit": "50",
}, {
  "invoice_id": "Blah Blah",
  "order_date": "03-02-2002",
  "product_name": "Always B +",
  "product_code": "foo@google.com.au",

  "sold_qty": "2",
  "buy_price": "2",
  "sell_price": "2",
  "discount": "2",
  "cost_price": "2",
  "sold_price": "2",
  "profit": "500",
}]


for (i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
  $('#tdata').append('<tr>' +
    '<td><a href="view_invoice.php?id=' + response[i].invoice_id + '">' + response[i].invoice_id + '</a></td>' +
    '<td>' + response[i].order_date + '</td>' +
    '<td><h6 class="mb-1">' + response[i].product_name + '</h6></td>' +
    '<td><h6 class="text-muted">' + response[i].product_code + '</h6></td>' +
    '<td>' + response[i].sold_qty + '</td>' +
    '<td>' + response[i].buy_price + '</td>' +
    '<td>' + response[i].sell_price + '</td>' +
    '<td>' + response[i].discount + '</td>' +
    '<td>' + response[i].cost_price + '</td>' +
    '<td>' + response[i].sold_price + '</td>' +
    '<td class="profits">' + response[i].profit + '</td>' +
    '</tr>'
  );
}


function calcSub() {
  var totalProfit = 0;
  $(".profits").each(function() {
    totalProfit += parseInt($(this).text());
    $("#total_profit").html(totalProfit);
  });
};

calcSub()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Invoice id</th>
      <th>Invoice Date</th>
      <th>Product Name</th>
      <th>Product Code</th>
      <th>Sale Qty</th>
      <th>Buy Price</th>
      <th>Sale Price</th>
      <th>Discount</th>
      <th>Cost Price</th>
      <th>Sold Price</th>
      <th>Profit</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="tdata">
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th colspan='10'>Total Profit</th>
      <th id="total_profit">0</th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

It might be a typo

```
var totalProfit= 0
```

need to be

```
var totalPrice= 0
```

Also you need to set the total value after you finish the iteration,full code listed below:

```
function calcSub(){
    var totalPrice= 0;
    $(".profits").each(function(index,element){
        totalPrice += parseInt($(element).text());//also,need to use text() instead of value()
    });
    $("#total_profit").html(totalPrice);//set profit after you finish the iteration
};
```

Comment: I have tried this solution. but not working. thanks for response.

Comment: @BanglaTiger Can you tell us what's the result of it,is the value still 0?

Comment: I can find nothing. @lucumt

Comment: @BanglaTiger can you provide us a jsfiddle demo so that others can help you analysis it?Based on your current code,there is not issue with it

Comment: @AlwaysHelping I don't know why it doesn't show any result in my page. There are minus values in the profit like (-100), does it affect the codes? thanks for help.

Comment: Something else is wrong with your code then . I recreated the exact code you provided and its working perfectly. I did not added anything on my own. Just fixed the code that really needed fixing. The last option is to share your minimal working example or debug your code line by line.

Comment: @BanglaTiger no `-100` value should not affect anything at all. it will minus automatically when the loop is running. Can you provided a demo response data you have  ?